# Convert stemmed word to root (or unconjugated) word

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stemming

I'm using NLTK to stem words from text, and doing some basic analytics with those words.  However, for display purposed, I want to convert those stems back to the "root" word (but not back to the same form or conjugation it started with).  For example:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> from nltk.stem import SnowballStemmer
>>> sn = SnowballStemmer("english")
>>> sn.stem("happiness")
u'happi'
>>> sn.stem("happy")
u'happi'

# What I want to do:
>>> some_unstem_function("happi")
u'happy'
```

Is there a function or method for doing this?

Answer (score 2):

There are different stemmers that you can try. An online tool that you can advise is [this](https://text-processing.com/). The lancaster stemmer can help you with your example, but you can try different stemmers and check which is better for your task.

```
from nltk.stem import lancaster
sn = lancaster.LancasterStemmer()
```